# Werkzeug on Python 3 raises "< not supported between instances of str and int"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I am trying to upgrade my flask app from Python 2.7 to 3.6.

The dev server runs. However when I try to access the home view, I am getting the rather unhelpful error:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2018 14:41:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 
ERROR:werkzeug:Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/med-portal/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 269, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/med-portal/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 260, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/med-portal/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 231, in write
    status < 200 or status in (204, 304)):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

```
# The Home page is accessible to authenticated users
@core_blueprint.route('')
@login_required  # Limits access to authenticated and active users
def home_page():
    print("Return home")
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**Version Info: Flask version 1.0.2, Werkzeug 0.14, Mac OSX High Sierra 10.13.6**

Comment: What versions of Flask and werkzeug are you running?

Comment: @KlausD. see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in werkzeug 0.14.1

See:
https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/commit/86f6d0bc7c410f70ac290eef018ee48a46563d4b

> Fixed a regression in the development server
>
> This fixes a type error being thrown for some requests.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem. I'm not sure why this was down-voted. I'm on Flask `0.12.1`, and was getting this error on Werkzeug `0.14.0`.  Please include comments with your down-votes folks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're error is outside of this file, most likely either in your `@login_required` decorator or in your flask-app using this blueprint.

I think you are returning a status code as a string somewhere e.g. `return Response, "200"` which is causing werkzeug total the comparison

Comment: I ended up uninstalling / installing Werkzeug and it worked. Unfortunately still clueless as to what it was and odds of now finding out are slim to none.

Comment: Strange, maybe some version mismatch somewhere.